# How to Iterate each row of csv for specific process

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

In csv there are contact with firstName, LastName, HouseholdName.

FName  LName  HouseName

ABC          XYZ             Family1

PQR         XYZ             Family1

In my case there are possibility of multiple contact belong to same family(householdName).

1. check whether household exist in table
2. If not then create household and create contact with new household id, else create contact with existing household ID found in step 1

But when transformation run, at first step it check household name for all row in table. As table is empty it return false and create household each time.

How I can avoid such situation without manipulating db.Please suggest

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I would load the HouseholdName fields in a separate transform before loading the names. Please post a screenshot of your transform. And how many rows are in your CSV typically?

Comment: Thanks for reply. There are around 50 to 60 thousand record. I have also uploaded screenshot of transformation.

Comment: YOU CAN USER INSERT/UPDATE STEP AND EASILY RESOLVE THIS PROBLEM.